# Google Fonts for Layouts

Tags: layout, fonts, profile, internal

Is there a way to add a google font into an internal css? Like for profile layouts?

I've tried embedding all three of these, but I can't get it to change the look of the font on my layout. Does google font work for internal css or only external?

```
<style>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script);
</style>
```

Comment: `<link>` tag won't appear inside `<style>` tag

Comment: What about a font-family property? Eg: `p { font-family: 'Dancing Script' }` to give all paragraphs this font family styling.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Fonts link needs to be embedded in the head element of an HTML or XHTML document. The thing to understand is that Google Fonts are handled through a Content Delivery Network (CDN). That means that Google hosts the fonts for you.

Here is an example they give on their website:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can reference the Google Fonts in an external stylesheet instead of internally as shown here.